# Update user roles in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I have three user roles: Student, Teacher, Admin.

If a user is a student I want to display the option to Elevate them to either Teacher or Admin in a dropdown and the same for the other roles eg. Teacher gets Admin and Student option.

Currently this looks like this:

Index

```
@if ($user->role == 'admin')
    <form action="/admin/users/{{ $user->id }}" method="POST">
        @csrf

        @method('PATCH')

        <input class="hidden" name="role" value="user">

        <button>Make User</button>
    </form>
@else
    <form action="/admin/users/{{ $user->id }}" method="POST">
        @csrf

        @method('PATCH')

        <input class="hidden" name="role"value="teacher">

        <button>Make Teacher</button>
    </form>
@endif
```

Controller

```
public function update(User $user)
{
    $attributes = request()->validate([
        'role' => ['required', Rule::exists('users', 'role')]
    ]);

    $user->update($attributes);

    return back()->with('success', 'User Updated!');
}
```

How would I be able to do an if statement to list all the roles except for the current role assigned to the user or perhaps this is better done in the controller instead?

And is it possible to put the role in a slug and then run a foreach so I don't repeat code?

Im new top Laravel so any help would be appreciated :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Provide all roles to your page.
2. Add to User `hasRole()` method if it does not exists.
3. Use [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) for validation.
4. Don't forget to get roles with a `$user` to avoid n+1 queries with `User::with('roles')->find($id)`.

```
@foreach($allRoles as $role)
    @if(! $user->hasRole($role)) 
        Your form
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How do I provide the '$allRoles' to my page? Could you provide code for the 'hasRoles()' in the controller? Sorry, I am very new to Laravel and still understanding it.

Comment: in your Controller: 
`view('your.path.to.page.index', ['allRoles' => Role::all()]);`

Comment: The `hasRole()` method should be in your User class and depending on how the access control system is implemented, check the presence of a role in it.

Comment: For example if you have a one-to-many relation:

`public function hasRole($role)
{
    return $this->role->id === $role->id;
}` but if the relationship is many-to-many, then you need to check it in another way

Comment: Okay I believe I sorted the allRoles issue by passing the roles as an array in my Controller. Currently I have a middleware called CheckRole.php which checks the users role and displays the correct views in the navigation. I am not authenticating users with a hasRoles() method.